# Don't get data saved in my configuration

Tags: system-config

In data.php

```
public function getConfiguration()
{

    $pathCheckout = 'orderattachments/order_attachments_checkout/';
    $pathCustomer = 'orderattachments/order_attachments_customer/';

    $config = array(
        'customer_can_add_new_attachments'  => Mage::getStoreConfig($pathCustomer . 'can_add_new_attachments'),
        'can_add_attachments'               => Mage::getStoreConfig($pathCheckout . 'can_add_attachments'),
    );
    return $config;
}
public function getCanAddAttachments()
{
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();
    return (bool) $config['can_add_attachments'];
}
```

in phtml:

```
$a =  Mage::helper('orderattachments')->getCanAddAttachments();
echo $a;
```

in $a value is null

Actually main problem is Mage::getStoreConfig return 0 value bt why please help me

system.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
    <tabs>
    <nextbits_extensions translate="label" module="orderattachments">
        <label>NextBits - Extensions</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </nextbits_extensions>
  </tabs>
  <sections>
    <orderattachments translate="label" module="orderattachments">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>OrderAttachments</label>
        <tab>nextbits_extensions</tab>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>301</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

        <groups>
           <order_attachments_checkout>
                <label>Order Checkout Settings</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <can_add_attachments translate="label">
                        <label>Can Add Attachments</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                              <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </can_add_attachments>
                </fields>
            </order_attachments_checkout>
            <order_attachments_customer>
                <label>Customer Account - Manage Attachments Settings</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <can_add_new_attachments translate="label">
                        <label>Can Add New Attachments</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </can_add_new_attachments>
                </fields>
            </order_attachments_customer>
           </groups>

    </orderattachments>
</sections>
 </config>
```

config.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Nextbits_OrderAttachments>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </Nextbits_OrderAttachments>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <orderattachments>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Nextbits_OrderAttachments</module>
                <frontName>orderattachments</frontName>
            </args>
        </orderattachments>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <orderattachments module="orderattachments">
                <file>orderattachments.xml</file>
            </orderattachments>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<global>
<models>
        <orderattachments>
            <class>Nextbits_Orderattachments_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>orderattachments_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </orderattachments>
         <orderattachments_mysql4>
            <class>Nextbits_Orderattachments_Model_Mysql4</class>
             <entities>
                <orderattachments>
                    <table>order_attachments</table>
                </orderattachments>
            </entities>
        </orderattachments_mysql4>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <orderattachments>
            <class>Nextbits_OrderAttachments_Block</class>
        </orderattachments>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <orderattachments>
            <class>Nextbits_OrderAttachments_Helper</class>
        </orderattachments>
    </helpers>  
    <events>
        <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
            <observers>
                <orderattachments>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>orderattachments/observer</class>
                    <method>saveOrderAttachments</method>
                </orderattachments>
            </observers>
        </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
    </events>
    <resources>
        <orderattachments_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Nextbits_OrderAttachments</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </orderattachments_setup>
        <orderattachments_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </orderattachments_write>
        <orderattachments_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </orderattachments_read>
    </resources>
</global> 
 <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Nextbits_OrderAttachments  before="Mage_Adminhtml">Nextbits_OrderAttachments_Adminhtml</Nextbits_OrderAttachments>
                </modules>
                <frontName>orderattachments</frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
   </admin>
  <adminhtml>
     <layout>
        <updates>
            <orderattachments>
                <file>orderattachments.xml</file>
            </orderattachments>
        </updates>
      </layout>
      <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                      <orderattachments translate="title"  module="orderattachments">
                                         <title>Order Attachments</title>
                                        <sort_order>10000</sort_order>
                                    </orderattachments>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
  </adminhtml>

  </config>
```

in this if in system.xml i change field name can_add-attachments to can_add-attachment that time i get value from config bt if i m not change it than why i m not get value?

Comment: can you please show your config.xml code and system.xml code?

Comment: You seem to be missing the `can_add_new_attachments` config option. And have you cleared the cache?

Comment: @Maikel no i m not missing that and yes cache is cleared

Comment: what is my mistake please tell me

Answer (score 3):

Try to fix the following:

### Check and correct namespaces

I see that you're mixing `Nextbits_Orderattachments` and `Nextbits_OrderAttachments` in your XML above. Correct the namespaces first (`Nextbixs_OrderAttachments`) and then try again if it works.

### Use getStoreConfigFlag()

You might also try to use the `getStoreConfigFlag()` method to retrieve the values in your helper class. They will always return a boolean. "false" and "0" evaluate as false. As you are using the `adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno` source model, this makes sense.

### Set a default value

Apart from this: I did not see you set a default value for this field. If you did not save data from the admin backend yet, there will be no value set. You can add them to the `default` section of your `config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <default>
        <orderattachments>
            <order_attachments_checkout>
                <can_add_attachments>0</can_add_attachments>
            </order_attachments_checkout>
        </orderattachments>
    </default>
</config>
```